# Executing the third step from Paypal IPN on Lambda Architecture

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I was reading the official documentations about the IPN here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Then i notice that:

> The IPN message authentication protocol consists of four steps:
>
> 1. PayPal HTTPS POSTs an IPN message to your listener that notifies it of an event.
> 2. Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal.
> 3. Your listener HTTPS POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal; >the message must contain the same fields (in the same order) as the original message and be encoded in the same way as the original message.
> 4. PayPal sends a single word back - either VERIFIED (if the message matches the original) or INVALID (if the message does not match the original).

On my current lambda endpoint that i used as the IPN notify URL i can do the steps 1 and 2. But how am i supposed to do steps 3 and 4 if i need to return a 200 with a blank body before it?

Comment: It seems you need to call PayPal URL for 3 from your lambda or some where in your code, isn't it?

Comment: @Nambari So steps 3 and 4 are done before step 2?

Comment: I don't have first hand experience with this, but based on steps described, 2- just acknowledges that PayPal POST was received by your listener (successfully, which is what 200 codes means), I am not sure what happens between 2 & 3, but 3- is where your listener sends data back to Paypal via another POST call 4- is where PayPal confirms the transaction. This is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Paypal expects step 2 to happen before steps 3 and 4. You cannot do this by using only one Lambda function.

You can use the listener Lambda function to put the payload as a message to SNS and let another Lambda function be invoked when SNS topic received a message.

See [Invoking Lambda functions using Amazon SNS notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html) for more details.